# Child relation is 'not a column" in Javascript Remoting

Tags: javascript-remoting, master-detail, childrecords

I'm running in to an issue where an object fetched from Salesforce through JS remoting is not able to be sent back because it has a relation field.

This is the setup:
A function retrieves a wrapper object with all required data. In this object there are contacts with occasional relationship data coming from a query like this:

```
 SELECT Id, (Select Id, [...] FROM Child_Relations__r WHERE [...]) FROM Contact WHERE [...]
```

This translates to a `Child_Relation__r` field on the JS object received on the front end. Now some values are changed on the wrapper object, the same JS object is sent as parameter to a different JS Remoting function, but I get a remoting error saying `Visualforce Remoting Exception: No such column 'Child_Relations__r' on sobject of type Contact`

Is JS remoting not suited to this kind of data or am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing something. Just check debug logs what is really performed. For debug purposes you can call remoting methods as anonymus apex

Comment: @kurunve There is nothing visible in the logs. I see variable assignments being done up until where the contacts would be processed, at which point the `invoke` method simply finishes execution. It even labels the remoting call a success since there is no visible exception being logged. This is why I suspect that it might be a parsing issue.

Comment: Then please post some code. Its pretty hard to guess what's wrong without code